# VS 2015 broken - can't open .cshtml file

Tags: razor, visual-studio-2015

I try to open a .cshtml file in VS 2015 and I get a message "The operation could not be completed"

I've tried repairing VS 2015, and it does this fine but still won't open a .cshtml file in my web project.

There's nothing in the ActivityLog.xml file about the error.

Comment: Completely reinstalling Visual Studio doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: From further investigation is seems related to my project as a new project created allows .cshtml files to be opened successfully.